# Port forward through another PC to another server

Tags: networking, proxy, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to make a port forward which I never tried before.

At work, almost all the ports are closed, apart from RDP and VPN ports.

I have app running on port trying to connect to server/computer (C) on port 1234 (which is blocked) at work (computer A). At home I have public IP and synology+windows server running (B). Then there is the final server (C) that I need to connect to.

Could something like this be possible? If so, how?

domain.com:1234 redirected through (VPN? SSH? proxy?) to Computer B port 3389 (RDP) which redirects the communication to domain.com:1234?

Comment: I'll try to simplify it a bit. 
Port 1234 is blocked at work, however 3389 and 5000 are open. I have synology and windows running at home with public IP I can connect to. Can I somehow get the port 1234 running at work?

Comment: If you can change the port your program listens on, sure. You may want to clean up / reformat the question. It parsed over it a couple times before it made any sense to me. The more descriptive you are with what you are trying to accomplish, and what you have already tried will attract better answers. Good question = good answers!